# Are big inner voice leaps permissible in the vi - V progression?

Tags: theory, chord-progressions, voice-leading

[image]

I am harmonizing a melody and that ^1 in m. 2 is supposed to be harmonized with a chord other than a tonic so I figured it must be a vi chord. The ^1 ^2 ^3 in the soprano usually works well with vi V I but I cant make it work somehow. If I want V on the second chord of m. 2 I will get two large leaps in the tenor and alto. I cant go lower because I have to use keyboard style and an octave is the limit. Can anyone recommend a different harmony using only the diatonic chords?

Here is the initial exercise
[image]

Comment: Should this be a completely homophonic texture? Can you revoice that vi chord in the right hand on the second eighth note of the measure?

Comment: Yes it is and no I cant revoice it...what about doubling the top B in the vi? Unless there is something better....  I added the initial exercise too.

Comment: Where it says "not I" could it be I6? or would that still count as I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the directions say "overlaps are allowed." This means that your tenor B on the downbeat of m. 2 can move up a fifth to F♯. This is above the alto's D in the prior chord–a voice overlap–but since this is explicitly allowed in the directions, it's pretty clear that the authors intended this leap to happen in this exercise.

In fact, this is the one main difference between keyboard and chorale style: in the former, voice overlaps are much more likely to occur, and are typically treated as correct.

Comment: Thanks. I thought that would be too  big a leap and it made me doubt my harmonization... This happens to me a lot. When the voice leading is smooth it gives me more confidence that what Im doing is right so when I need to make such a big leap I wonder if other chords might be more suitable.

Comment: would changing the 1st chord of m2 from vi to VI6 be a better harmonization? The following V chord could actually be a V65 with 2 in the soprano.